# How do I optimize a bioinformatics pipeline for novel data sets?

Tags: cross-validation, bioinformatics, hyperparameter, optimization

**Context:** I'm putting the finishing touches on a bioinformatics pipeline for omics data. There are many sequential interlocking parts (e.g. model fitting, regression, classification, clustering, etc). The final pipeline will be packaged up for use by other people on novel data.

**Problem:** I don't want to change the main logic of the analysis. But there were many small choices I made and I'd like to optimize these. A couple examples are:

- Model selection by AIC vs AICc vs BIC
- Classifier type
- Balanced vs non-balanced classification training data

Obviously I'd like to make the best analysis pipeline I can.

However, I only have access to 5 data sets of varying quality, and the optimal pipeline, as measured by the final output, differs between the data sets. (For example, the best analysis for data set 1 is AICc + balanced, but for data set 5 it's BIC + non-balanced.) Further, although I know the format, I don't know exactly what the end users' data sets will look like.

**Question:** How do I optimize a pipeline for data sets I've never seen, when from the small number of data sets I have, there appears to be a range of good ways to run the analysis?

Is there a **cross-validation** scheme that would work using my small number of data sets? Am I trying to fine tune it too much? E.g. should I just leave these choices as switches in a config file that the user can fiddle with?

This is a new problem for me. I'm used to dealing with one data set (mine), in which case a route to the best analysis is usually clear.